# Copying an MicroSD Card to another Card with a different size

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-3

I am using a **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V.1.2** with **Raspbian Jessie**

I Used **Win32DiskImager** to Read from an **SanDisk Extreme 32 GB MicroSD Card**, and then Used it to Write to an **SanDisk Ultra 64 GB MicroSD Card**.

When I Booted from the **64 GB MircoSD Card**, It only says that it is only 30 GB instead of 64 GB.

I used the command to check the available storage :

> df -h

---

The **32 GB MicroSD Card** :

[image: The 32 GB MicroSD Card]

---

The **64 GB MicroSD Card** :

[image: It Says 30 GB instead of 64 GB]

---

And both of the MicroSD Card looked quite similar.

When I Plugged Those two MircoSD Card to My Computer running Windows 10, And I Opened `Computer Management > Storage > Device Management`, And I saw this :

---

The **32 GB MicroSD Card** :

[image: 32 GB MicroSD Card]

---

The **64 GB MicroSD Card** :

[image: 64 GB MicroSD Card]

---

This shows that when I cloned the 32 GB MicroSD Card to the 64 GB MicroSD Card, It also copied the 30 GB Partition.

So is there any way to make the 64 GB MicroSD Card read as 64 GB (or atleast about 59 GBs) ?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from a small card to a larger one is relatively easy. In fact, it's what most people do every time they install Raspbian. Remember when you first installed the OS and you had to expand the file system? You need to do that again.

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Select `Expand Filesystem`. At the time of writing, this is option number 1.
3. Restart your RPi.

Once the RPi has finished restarting, you should be able to use the entire card.